# Post with Custom Permalinks

Tags: permalinks

My permalinks are set like:

`http://myblog.com/%category%/%postname%/`

Everything works fine.

But I am looking for a way to set the permalink like the following for only some posts (10-11 posts).

`http://myblog.com/%postname%/`

I want this because I am merging two WordPress websites and I don't want to loose the posts of the other website which are already published on Facebook etc with the old permalink structure.

Comment: Instead of a WordPress solution I would recommend altering the htaccess for these few posts and redirect them.

Comment: @websupporter Facebook doesn't follow redirects, once a URL is in graph, it can't be changed without losing all prior activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the Rewrite API. Since you have a fixed set of posts you could do the following:

```
 add_action( 'init', 'rewrite_old_slugs' );
 function rewrite_old_slugs(){
    $post_slugs = array(
        'post-1' => 1,
        'post-2' => 2 
    );

    foreach( $post_slugs as $slug => $new_id )
        add_rewrite_rule( $slug . '?$', 'index.php?p=' . $new_id, 'top' );
 }
```

I've created a post_slugs array where the array keys are the old slugs and the array values are the post ids.

If you go this way, you have to go to Settings > Permalinks and hit the update-button, so the rules are active.

This solution works for posts. If you need it for pages, you need to rewrite the URLs to

```
index.php?page_id=
```